# React Select adjust the first option layout

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to adjust the first option to be centered in the option in the React Select but nothing it is working for that ( all other adjustments in the CSS of React Select it is working). here the code that I'm using in the option values:

```
    const option = (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    background: state.isSelected ? theme.colors.green600 : theme.colors.white,
    color: state.isSelected ? theme.colors.white : theme.colors.grey500,
    display: 'flex',
    fontFamily: 'CircularStd',
    lineHeight: '18px',
    fontSize: '14px',
    ':nth-child(0) ': {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
    },
});
```

obs: the option it is inside of customStyles, and I'm passing into the Select, like styles={customStyles}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to style the first option you may want to target the `:first-child` of the `MenuList`. Here is the example

```
const styles = {
  menuList: (provided, state) => {
    return {
      ...provided,
      "& :first-child": {
        textAlign: "center"
      }
    };
  }
};
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit react-select Style First Option Only]